# Symfony: issue with switching context

Tags: symfony1

I am using Symfony 1.2 and I have some issues switching context.

This code was working fine:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('account', 'prod', false);
$context = sfContext::createInstance($configuration, 'account-prod');

$userToLogin = PcUserPeer::retrieveByEmailAddress("myemail@example.com");
Auth::login($context->getUser(), $userToLogin, false, false);

echo "all done.";
```

At some point requirements changed and I needed to use the 'public' application before the 'account' one.
Then I changed to:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

// {{{ new code:
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('public', 'prod', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration);    
// some code using the public app...
// }}}    


$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('account', 'prod', false);
$context = sfContext::createInstance($configuration, 'account-prod');
// {{{ new code:
sfContext::switchTo('account-prod');
// }}}  

$userToLogin = PcUserPeer::retrieveByEmailAddress("myemail@example.com");
CustomAuth::login($context->getUser(), $userToLogin, false, false);

echo "all done.";
```

Basically I added a switchTo call.

After the change, the code got broken and the error message is this:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/html/myproj/symfony/storage/sfPDOSessionStorage.class.php on line 109
```

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony is trying to load the session storage object. I suppose there is a problem with your new environment's configuration.

Check

```
/apps/public/config/factories.yml
```

Look for "storage" and try to find out how is it different from the other app's configuration.

Comment: I received the identical error and some investigation eventually showed that Aston was correct that my environment was broken.  Since this was working for dan at one point, his problem may have differed.  For those who are just getting their environment up and running, double-check that php can access the database.  In my case, the php.ini was broken and not accessing the db.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without a backtrace/more info what is triggering the error. It looks like you are using sessions stored in a database, and that a query related to that is failing.

Try setting the third argument to getApplicationConfiguration to true (which will turn debug on) and see if you get more output.

At a guess, it looks like the account app is using PDO session storage, and is failing to connect to the database or something?